# Remotely connect to oracle database by powershell

Tags: oracle, powershell

Below is my Oracle query which is running via PowerShell. It is working fine with no error if I am running it locally on that machine.

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("E:\oracle\product\11.2.0\ODP.NET\bin\2.x\Oracle.DataAccess.dll")

$constr = "User Id=system;Password=pass;Data Source=API"
$conn= New-Object Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection($constr)
$conn.Open()
$sql="select * from dba_users"
$command = New-Object Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand($sql,$conn)
$reader=$command.ExecuteReader()

while($reader.Read()){
  $reader.GetString(0)
}

$conn.Close()
```

I want to run same query on other machine from this machine. I can say I want to run it remotely.

When I run it I am getting this error:

> Exception calling "Open" with "0" argument(s): "ORA-12541: TNS:no
>   listener"

I can't add entry in Tnsora file.

Can anybody advise me any alternative way to achive this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't modify the tnsora, you have to use either `EZConnect` or the `connect descriptor` as your [connection string](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e41945/concepts.htm#NETAG253). Try this:

```
$userId = 'system'
$password = 'pass'
$host = 'ip or hostname'
$port = '1521'
$serviceName = 'Your service name'

$constr = "User Id=$userId;Password=$password;Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=$host)(PORT=$port))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=$serviceName)))"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try and let you know.

Comment: One more question $serviceName = 'Your service name'. What do i need to put in service name. It would be database name or something else

Comment: Yes, the database name. For further information about the connect descriptor I suggested you to use, look at the link I provided you ;-)